# Can't find where infinite loop occurs

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm making a program where the user enters 30 days of closing stock prices and the program finds the lowest and highest price.

After the user enters the data the program won't continue.

```
double highest = stockPrices[0];
double lowest = stockPrices[0];

for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(stockPrices) + 1; j++) {
     if(stockPrices[j] > highest) {
      highest = stockPrices[j];
     }   
     if(stockPrices[j] < lowest) {
      lowest = stockPrices[j];
     } 
}
```

I can't seem to find where the infinite loop is however.

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(stockPrices) + 1; i++) {
    cin >> stockPrices[i];
}
```

This part works fine which is why I didn't realize my upperbound is incorrect
EDIT: I think this part works fine

Comment: `sizeof(stockPrices)` is `sizeof(double)` times the number of elements. It's probably a fair bit bigger than you expected. That's actually assuming you declared it like `double stockPrices[N];` earlier that function.

Comment: There's only one loop there, so there should be no trouble finding it. But what makes you think it's infinite?

Comment: @RobKennedy it won't run past the last `cin`

Comment: @chris What do you mean by that? I'm new to C++. I thought `sizeof` is comparable to `array.length()`

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion No, `sizeof` gives the size of an object in bytes.

Comment: What `cin`? Post the code with the `cin`.

Comment: @DanielFischer so the upper bound is a lot higher than expected. What is the proper function if I wanted to call something equivalent to `array.length()`

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion, In C++, use `std::array` or `std::vector`. They have `size()` functions and semantics you'd expect. Other containers work too if they offer a particular quality you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not enough code to figure out where your problem is. But just in that snippet you probably have the wrong upper bound:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(stockPrices) / sizeof(stockPrices[0]); j++)
```

`sizeof` gives the size of an object in bytes. For an array that's the number of items × the size of one item. So to get the number of items you need to divide `sizeof` by the size of one item.

And you probably don't want the `+1` either.

Mind you, the loop you wrote will terminate with or without this correction. It'll run past the end of the array in your version and access illegal memory, which could crash the program, but it won't loop forever.

---

The same thing applies to your second loop. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(stockPrices) / sizeof(stockPrices[0]); i++)
{
    cin >> stockPrices[i];
}
```

And here the incorrect upper bound probably *is* the culprit. Your original loop will try to read more than 30 values. If there are only 30 supplied then the program will hang on the 31st `cin >> stockPrices[i]` waiting for more numbers to be entered.

Comment: This is where the loop occurs because the code before it works fine.